# Unexpected result with Python reversed()

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
[print(' '.join(list(reversed([str(j) for j in range(i * n + n, i * n, -1)])))) if i % 2 == 1 else print(' '.join([str(j) for j in range(i * n + 1, i * n + n + 1)])) for i in range(n)]
```

Expected results:

```
n: 5
1 2 3 4 5
10 9 8 7 6
11 12 13 14 15
20 19 18 17 16
21 22 23 24 25
```

Actual result:

```
n: 5
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Why doesn't `reversed()` work here, and what do I need to fix to match the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that your range had a -1 increment which in turn was reversed by the `reverse()` call.  So, if we take the reverse() out, we get the desired results:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
[ print(' '.join(list([str(j) for j in range(i * n + n, i * n,-1)]))) if i % 2 == 1 else print(' '.join([str(j) for j in range(i * n + 1, i * n + n + 1)])) for i in range(n) ]
```

With these results:

```
n: 5
1 2 3 4 5
10 9 8 7 6
11 12 13 14 15
20 19 18 17 16
21 22 23 24 25
```

Alternatively, you can remove the -1 increment from your range() statement.  You'll also need to change the start and end of the range accordingly.    Once we change the range from `range(i * n + n, i * n,-1)` to `range(i * n + 1 , i * n + n + 1)`, we get this code (and the same results:

```
n = int(input('n: '))
[print(' '.join(list(reversed([str(j) for j in range(i * n + 1 , i * n + n + 1)])))) if i % 2 == 1 else print(' '.join([str(j) for j in range(i * n + 1, i * n + n + 1)])) for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters to `range()` already reverse the values -- what you're doing amounts to performing a reverse operation twice.

You shouldn't really be using a list comprehension for side effects, but to resolve your immediate issue, remove `reversed()`:

```py
n = int(input('n: '))
[print(' '.join(list([str(j) for j in range(i * n + n, i * n, -1)]))) if i % 2 == 1 else print(' '.join([str(j) for j in range(i * n + 1, i * n + n + 1)])) for i in range(n)]
```

And for completeness, here is a version of your code that does not make use of a list comprehension:

```py
n = int(input('n: '))

for i in range(n):
    elements = list(map(str, range(i * n + 1, (i + 1) * n + 1)))
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(' '.join(elements))
    else:
        print(' '.join(reversed(elements)))
```

These output:

```py
1 2 3 4 5
10 9 8 7 6
11 12 13 14 15
20 19 18 17 16
21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you wish to continue using a single list comprehension, it pairs well with a conditional expression to either reverse the iterator or not and then convert to a list.

The second clause in the comprehension that introduces `r` is a list with only one element. This allows us to not have to recalculate `r` twice.

```
[list(r if i % 2 == 0 else reversed(r))
  for i in range(n) 
  for r in [range(i * n + 1, i * n + 1 + n)]]
```

For `n` being `5` this will yield:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 19, 18, 17, 16], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

We can then generate a list of strings.

```
[' '.join(map(str, (r if i % 2 == 0 else reversed(r))))
  for i in range(n) 
  for r in [range(i * n + 1, i * n + 1 + n)]]
```

Yields:

```
['1 2 3 4 5', '10 9 8 7 6', '11 12 13 14 15', '20 19 18 17 16', '21 22 23 24 25']
```

And then we join those with newlines. The list comprehension is now unnecessary, and we can pass a generator expression to `str.join`.

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, (r if i % 2 == 0 else reversed(r))))
  for i in range(n) 
  for r in [range(i * n + 1, i * n + 1 + n)])
```

We get:

```
'1 2 3 4 5\n10 9 8 7 6\n11 12 13 14 15\n20 19 18 17 16\n21 22 23 24 25'
```

Then you just have to print that.